# Vectorizing by splitting matrix by rows unequally

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization, document-classification

I have `X_test` which is a matrix of size `967874 x 3` where the columns are: `doc#, wordID, wordCount`, and there's 7505 unique doc#'s (`length(unique(X_test(:,1))) == length(Y_test) == 7505`). The matrix rows are also already sorted according to the doc#'s column.

I also have a `likelihoods` matrix of size `61188 x 20` where the rows are all possible wordIDs, and the columns are different classes (`length(unique(Y_test))==20`)

**The result I'm trying to obtain is** a matrix of size `7505 x 20` where each row signifies a different document and contains, for each class (column), the sum of the wordCounts of the values in the likelihood matrix rows which correspond to the wordIDs for that document (trying to think of better phrasing...)

My first thought was to rearrange this 2D matrix into a 3D matrix according to doc#s, but the number of rows for each unique doc# are unequal. I also think making a cell array of 7505 matrices isn't a great idea, but may be wrong about that.

**It's probably more explanatory if I just show the code I have that works**, but is slow because it iterates through each of the 7505 documents:

```
probabilities = zeros(length(Y_test),nClasses); % 7505 x 20
for n=1:length(Y_test) % 7505 iterations
    doc = X_test(X_test(:,1)==n,:);
    result = bsxfun(@times, doc(:,3), log(likelihoods(doc(:,2),:)));
    % result ends up size length(doc) x 20   
    probabilities(n,:) = sum(result);
end
```

for context, this is what I use the probabilities matrix for:

```
% MAP decision rule
probabilities = bsxfun(@plus, probabilities, logpriors'); % add priors
[~,predictions] = max(probabilities,[],2);
CCR = sum(predictions==Y_test)/length(Y_test); % correct classification rate
fprintf('Correct classification percentage: %0.2f%%\n\n', CCR*100);
```

**edit**: so I separated the matrix into a cell array according to doc#'s, but don't know how to apply `bsxfun` to all arrays in a cell at the same time.

```
counts = histc(X_test(:,1),unique(X_test(:,1)));
testdocs = mat2cell(X_test,counts);
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code? The bottleneck you might solve is in the `doc = ...`, as this requires to do comparison of all the elements of X_test 7000 times. A single pass could work (generating all the doc{m} you need at once), and you would later just use doc{m} in the same loop.
If the bottleneck is in `result=...`, I don't think you can do much. This code operates on each element just once.

To profile you could use simple `tic for ... doc{m} = X_test...; end toc`, and then use `doc{m}` instead of `doc` later on (omitting `doc = ...` line).

Comment: Oh wow I must be overtired I just replaced `doc` with `testdocs{n}` and it calculated everything almost instantly. Thanks ;)